# Understanding the iquidus API settings

Tags: blockchain, altcoin-development, blockexplorer

I am trying to understand what values I am being asked for in the settings.json to install the block explorer for Iquidus. I know how to get the genesis block as I have hard coded it when I did a fork to create a new altcoin, however, I am unsure how to get the genesis_tx. I know you can convert it from the genesis block but I am unsure how?

"genesis": {
"genesis_tx": " ",
"genesis_block": " "}

In terms of the API settings, they are asking for an address, blockindex, blockhash, and txhash. The blockindex can be any value within your block height... so do I pick just any one value for the index with the corresponding address in the transaction list? Also, how do I get the txhash and the blockhash? These values to my understanding are subject to change and I know they are stored in the blockchain... does anyone know how I can retrieve this information?

"api": {
"blockindex": " ",
"blockhash": " ",
"txhash": " ",
"address": " "
},

I appreciate your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out your blockhash with index=0
(normally in your coind debug window,s you can: do a

getblockhash 0
(0 = genesis block number)

With the return value from that, you do a
getblock xxxx

eg:

```
￼
getblockhash 0
 ￼
5597f25c062a3038c7fd815fe46c67dedfcb3c839fbc8e01ed4044540d08fe48

￼
getblock 5597f25c062a3038c7fd815fe46c67dedfcb3c839fbc8e01ed4044540d08fe48

{
"hash" : "5597f25c062a3038c7fd815fe46c67dedfcb3c839fbc8e01ed4044540d08fe48",
"confirmations" : 4142183,
"size" : 240,
"height" : 0,
"version" : 1,
"merkleroot" : "2bad42ac6e0ccc4808d8df0fd50ac8634eea335b1412b1ef52864b430a87b262",
"tx" : [
"2bad42ac6e0ccc4808d8df0fd50ac8634eea335b1412b1ef52864b430a87b262"
],
"time" : 1394102925,
"nonce" : 2482334,
"bits" : "1e0ffff0",
"difficulty" : 0.00024414,
"nextblockhash" : "df34593a55b7ed0ff076766805023c8262fe26c84ba8624b77abae446c402dea"
}
```